# Opening xv6 File System Image (fs.img) in Read-Only Mode Fails

Tags: c, ubuntu, operating-system, filesystems, xv6

I'm working with the xv6 operating system and have compiled it successfully, generating the file system image fs.img. I'm attempting to open this image in read-only mode from user space (outside the xv6 environment) using the following code:

```
int fd = open("fs.img", O_RDONLY);
```

However, the open call is failing, and I'm unable to access the file descriptor. I'm not using any xv6-specific APIs or running this code within the xv6 emulator; I'm trying to access the file system image directly from a regular user space program.

What could be the reason for this failure? Are there any specific considerations or permissions required to access the fs.img file in this manner?

Comment: The first thing I would rule out is if your working directory is set to somewhere other than where the file is. Use the full pathname to the file and see if you get a different result.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it is not working (I've tried to provide absolute path)

Comment: "What could be the reason for this failure?" Did you check `errno` for the error code or did you try `perror` to print an error message? E.g. `perror("Cannot open image file\n");`